# Transform effect for svg text

Tags: svg

I'm trying to build a SVG text editor which allows user to modify text content by typing. I'm wondering to know that if it's possible to implement the text effect like the demo below?

I could use Ai to build the text transform effect then save it with svg format. But the text would become "paths", so user won't be able to modify the text content by typing.

This is the demo made by Ai:
https://jsfiddle.net/m31s7eg7/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 167.92 152.98"><title>love</title><path d="M24.7,33.66c2.35-2.28,3.56-3.37,6-5.45v86.67a104.2,104.2,0,0,0,21.83,11.45V140A171.09,171.09,0,0,1,24.7,120Z" transform="translate(-24.7)"/><path d="M106.84,75.22c0,12.55-2.87,84.31-27.47,77.28C56.72,146,54,98.41,54,78c0-21,2.78-70.36,26.24-77C103.87-5.82,106.83,62.29,106.84,75.22Zm-45.25,2.4c0,16.42,3,56.64,18.21,59.53,15.73,3,18.9-48.37,18.9-61,0-13-3.47-62.36-18.81-59.67C64.3,19.21,61.59,60.86,61.59,77.61Z" transform="translate(-24.7)"/><path d="M129.87,151.8Q120,75.93,110.48,0c3.33,0,5,.13,8.31.4Q123.38,38.05,128,75.7c2.29,18.46,4.61,36.92,6.28,55.45l.17,0c1.79-18.44,4.18-36.8,6.65-55.16q4.71-34.27,9.68-68.51c3.12,1.15,4.67,1.77,7.71,3.14C151.19,57,144.61,103.5,138.21,150,134.89,150.86,133.22,151.21,129.87,151.8Z" transform="translate(-24.7)"/><path d="M190.58,79.62c-7.21.41-11.11.6-19.26.9v42.93a100,100,0,0,0,21.3-12.84c0,3.74,0,5.61,0,9.35a170.91,170.91,0,0,1-28.17,20.23q0-63.38,0-126.76A171.61,171.61,0,0,1,191.6,32.69c0,3.82,0,5.73,0,9.56a100.36,100.36,0,0,0-20.28-12.08V67.8c8.15.74,12,1.18,19.26,2.19Z" transform="translate(-24.7)"/></svg>
```

Is there any idea to achieve this? maybe transform text on server side?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not aware of any consistent way you can do this, without it being a path.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do this with pure SVG.  One solution would be to draw the SVG to a Canvas and use a bimap filter. Another solution would be to do the transform yourself after reading the text glyphs with a library like [opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org/).

Comment: I found this http://jsfiddle.net/david7418/xvpzcbhp/. Probably this could be used in this project.